# Postgresql and flask connection

Tags: postgresql, flask, mod-wsgi, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm using flask on `python3`.

Migrate script is working no error from it. Main app is running fine too. 
I'm using `postgresql` when I run migrate everything run fine but then somehow when I go in `postgres` shell I cannot see any table being created.

**modesl.py**

```
from imports import db
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class UserInfo(db.Model):

    __tablename_ = 'user_info'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    posts = relationship('UserPosts', backref='posts')

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
            return '{}-{}'.format(self.username, self.email)
```

As you can see I have two tables there but I just see `user_info` in my database because I manually created it but the other table I cannot see.

```
export DATABASE_URL="postgresql:user:password@localhost/registration"

tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.049888 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 185, in reraise, referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.049900 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358]     raise value.with_traceback(tb), referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.049919 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context, referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.049931 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358]     context), referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.049951 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute, referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.049962 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358]     cursor.execute(statement, parameters), referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.050034 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358] sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column user_info.password does not exist, referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.050088 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358] LINE 1: ...nfo_username, user_info.email AS user_info_email, user_info...., referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.050106 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358]                                                              ^, referer: http://localhost/login/
[Fri Oct 07 17:21:56.050122 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19131:tid 140331236435712] [client 174.58.31.189:34358]  [SQL: 'SELECT user_info.id AS user_info_id, user_info.username AS user_info_username, user_info.email AS user_info_email, user_info.password AS user_info_password \\nFROM user_info'], referer: http://localhost/login/
```

I don't know if I'm setting my connection to the database the right way or if nothing is being created at all .

Thanks.

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
import os

import __init__

__init__.app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
migrate = Migrate(__init__.app, __init__.db)
manager = Manager(__init__.app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Comment: How are you running your migrations? Are you sure that the app you use for that is aware of your models? Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13917608) to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i included my manage.py module and yes the main app is aware it was displaying data from database that i entered manually

Comment: The error in the traceback you posted above is `column user_info.password does not exist`. Seems you have discrepancies between your models and your actual database.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that there are two tables supposed to be present, but I only see one being defined in your `models.py` file for `UserInfo`. Do you have `UserPosts` defined elsewhere in the file as well, or have you only created the relationship to it? If not, you should create a model for it as well.

Another thing to point out is that instead of importing `ForeignKey` and `relationship` from `sqlalchemy`, you should be using `db.relationship()` and `db.ForeignKey()`

I can also see that your URL is missing a couple characters. Instead of `"postgresql:user:password@localhost/registration"` your URL should look like `"postgresql://user:password@localhost/registration"`

Finally, are you migrating and upgrading with your `manage.py` file or only migrating? After running `python manage.py db migrate` you should then follow it with `python manage.py db upgrade`. The `migrate` command creates the migration script, while the `upgrade` command is what executes it and writes your changes to the database.

One last thing to note is that if you change your `user_info` model while logged into the server and run migrations on those, sometimes there will be discrepancies between what is stored in the session and what is on the database. This can cause the app to crash similar to the error you posted from wsgi, leading me to believe that that may have happened here as well. Make sure to log out before messing with the database, but if that does happen you should be able to just clear your cookies to delete the session and make the error go away.